# Best one class classifier for small sample size

Tags: algorithm, machine-learning, classification, libsvm

I have a high-(600-)dimensional dataset and I have a very small sample size (+- 100 datapoints) from one class. The nature of data make it very hard to generate outliers, so I need to  I need to train a one class classifier on these data.

Do you have experience with one class classification? What is the best algorithm for small sample size and high dimensionality? I was thinking about using one class SVM from libsvm library, is it a good choice?

Thanks for advice

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you wanted to take the path of neural networks then:

For high dimensionality single class classification you probably would want a needle-in-haystack style training regiment.

I believe the most notable of these would be the [adaptive gradient](http://www.magicbroom.info/Papers/DuchiHaSi10.pdf).

Otherwise, high dimensionality is handled efficiently by SVMs and the fact that outliers are unlikely further strengthens the case for using a boundary-based algorithm.